# v-autocomplete - filter by values that start with the input value

Tags: vuetify.js

By default it filters by any value containing the input value, regardless the position of this one.

I would like to filter by values that start with the input value.

Example:

-Values: "apple", "pplea", "eapple"

-Input: "app"

-Actual output: "apple", "pplea", "eapple"

-Expected output: "apple"

Is it possible to do this? I can't find it in the props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` method which is provided by Vuetify,

So it can be used like this,
`<v-autocomplete v-model="select" :items="items" label="Pick a fruit" :filter="getList"></v-autocomplete>`

the getList method as follows,

`getList  (item, queryText, itemText) {
    return itemText.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(queryText.toLocaleLowerCase())
}`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVQxyZ?editors=1010

Hope it helps!